# Is there any limitation of capN for setcap?

Tags: linux, linux-capabilities

I am trying to use setcap to give an app some capabilities on linux.

It is working well with less than or equal to 18 caps.

```
$ setcap "0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,10,12,13,14,16,17,18,19,21"+eip test_app
$ getcap test_app
test_app cap_chown,cap_dac_override,cap_dac_read_search,cap_fowner,cap_fsetid,cap_kill,cap_setgid,cap_setuid,cap_setpcap,cap_net_bind_service,cap_net_admin,cap_net_raw,cap_ipc_lock,cap_sys_module,cap_sys_rawio,cap_sys_chroot,cap_sys_ptrace,cap_sys_admin=eip
$
```

But when I give greater than 18 caps, it is not working.
It looks like that I give the caps 9,11,15,20,22,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36 to setcap, but I actually gave 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,10,12,13,14,16,17,18,19,21,23.

```
$ setcap "0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,10,12,13,14,16,17,18,19,21,23"+eip test_app
$ getcap test_app
test_app =eip cap_linux_immutable,cap_net_broadcast,cap_ipc_owner,cap_sys_pacct,cap_sys_boot,cap_sys_resource,cap_sys_time,cap_sys_tty_config,cap_mknod,cap_lease,cap_audit_write,cap_audit_control,cap_setfcap,cap_mac_override,cap_mac_admin,cap_syslog,cap_wake_alarm,cap_block_suspend-eip
$
```

The linux kernel version is 3.10.0.

Thanks

I can't find any clue why this issue is happened.

Answer (score 0):

The Linux kernel has space for 64 capabilities. At present, only 41 of them are defined. [capability.h](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/include/uapi/linux/capability.h).

On your system, you can do this to list them all (`cap_chown`=0, `cap_dac_override`=1, etc):

```
$ grep CapBnd /proc/1/status
CapBnd: 000001ffffffffff
$ capsh --decode=000001ffffffffff
0x000001ffffffffff=cap_chown,cap_dac_override,cap_dac_read_search,cap_fowner,cap_fsetid,cap_kill,cap_setgid,cap_setuid,cap_setpcap,cap_linux_immutable,cap_net_bind_service,cap_net_broadcast,cap_net_admin,cap_net_raw,cap_ipc_lock,cap_ipc_owner,cap_sys_module,cap_sys_rawio,cap_sys_chroot,cap_sys_ptrace,cap_sys_pacct,cap_sys_admin,cap_sys_boot,cap_sys_nice,cap_sys_resource,cap_sys_time,cap_sys_tty_config,cap_mknod,cap_lease,cap_audit_write,cap_audit_control,cap_setfcap,cap_mac_override,cap_mac_admin,cap_syslog,cap_wake_alarm,cap_block_suspend,cap_audit_read,cap_perfmon,cap_bpf,cap_checkpoint_restore
```

Update 2023-10-06:

The string output syntax of `getcap` might be confusing you:

```
=eip cap_linux_immutable,...,cap_block_suspend-eip
```

means "`=eip`" (all capabilities known to the system) " `cap_linux_immutable,...,-eip`" (minus these ones). Specifically, once you have explicitly listed enough capabilities, it is more efficient to summarize what you have as *everything minus a list* instead of *here is the full list*. As you add more and more capabilities to your list you eventually pass the point where listing what you don't have is less complicated.

The [`cap_from_text`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/cap_to_text) man page has some explanation of this text output format. I found some more examples of the same format behavior in the [Go package function `cap.FromText()`](https://pkg.go.dev/kernel.org/pub/linux/libs/security/libcap/cap#FromText).

Comment: Thank you Tinkerer! The caps I configured are listed by the command. Maybe getcap can't show the all caps I configured..

Comment: @ByeongYoonSo I've updated my answer. I think the `getcap` syntax may have caused you some confusion.